# Featured tag displayed in profile

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

In [my SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327651/nha), the only `top tag` displayed is `node.js`.

However if you look closely (picture below), you can see that it :

- `node.js` : a score of 80 comes from 13 posts
- `clojure` : a score of 40 comes from 60 posts

Now one could argue that I'm a good Node developer and a bad Clojure one. But in this case I would rather think that the popularity of JavaScript/Node makes for more upvotes.

Is there a way to display the `top tag` differently ? Maybe a `most active` tag ? Maybe display both `node.js` and `clojure` ?

Can I in any way to influence how the profile is displayed ? I am not asking to display fake data of course, but to be able to influence the presentation : "I would like you to display more information about X if possible".

[image: my SO profile at the moment]

*Note:* I did tag this post `feature-request`, since if something like that doesn't exist, it would be useful to me.

Comment: Good or bad, everything on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange is measured by reputation/votes. Top Users, Hot Questions, etc... so if this request is done and we can choose the tag, it better be changed to "Featured tag" to be more accurate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's probably a much better wording, yes.